# Apache Rewrite Fails Without [R] Flag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've just started working with Apache, and ran into an odd issue with using RewriteRule to redirect users. I want to create a clean URL to link to an 'about' page.
I want users to be able to type, for example, `mywebsite/about` in the address bar and be directed to `mywebsite/a/b/about_files` without changing the address bar.

I am placing the redirect rules in the Apache sites `config` file (not `.htaccess`), and the following works correctly, but changes the site address bar:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...

   DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule "^/about$" "/a/b/about_files" [R]

...
</VirtualHost>
```

From the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) that I've found, it looks like I should be able to replace that `[R]` flag with `[PT]` to retain `about` in the address bar, but when I do, I simply get a `404 error`. Replacing `[R]` with `[L]` or other flags also produces a `404`. I haven't found any verified advice on why this behaviour occurs or how to fix it ...?

Thanks

Comment: So `/a/b/about_files` is a physical filesystem path? - no file extension?

Comment: If you're trying to make `/about/foo.jpg` load `/a/b/about_files/foo.jpg` you'll need a different rewrite rule.

Comment: Yes ,`/a/b/about_files` is a file path - no extension - I'm assuming it would default to the `index.html` file in that location. On further digging, it looks like my issue may have come up because `/a/b/about_files` isn't under my DocumentRoot. It's from the server root. I've attempted using `Alias` instead, but the problem persists

Comment: I'm assuming this information will not be relevant to my Apache problem, but the application here is to make a clean url to access an html report produced by a Jenkins build on my Jenkins server. Likely not relevant, but I figured I'd put it out there in case people have had issues working with those two together.

Comment: it rewrites to the `/var/www/html/a/b/about_files`. Otherwise use an `Alias /about /a/b/about_files` and specify a `<Directory "/a/b"><Files "about_files">....` with proper permissions.